# How to type Unicode Character on Windows in Browser?

Tags: windows, unicode, char, unicode-string

I'm trying to find a way typing [this Unicode Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2c60/index.htm) while I am inside my browser (Firefox) on Windows.

**String:** `ALT +1c35`

**Method I tried:**

> This method works regardless of any of your language settings, but is the most cumbersome to type.
>
> Press and hold down the Alt key.
> Press the + (plus) key on the numeric keypad.
> Type the hexidecimal unicode value.
> Release the Alt key.
>
> Alas, this appears to require a registry setting. It was already set on my computer, but some readers report that this method didn't
> work for them, and this is probably why. If you don't know what the
> registry is, please don't try this. Under HKEY_Current_User/Control
> Panel/Input Method, set EnableHexNumpad to "1". If you have to add it,
> set the type to be REG_SZ.
>
> [Source](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2c60/browsertest.htm)

**Problem:** If you hold `ALT` and press `c` the browser jumps into the browser menu.

I am not satisfied with copy-paste this character from my desktop or a website everytime I need it in forums, etc.. I already set the registry key mentioned in the quote above.

Is there any method which allows me to type it, while I'm in my browser?

Comment: Did you read the rest of the article linked to in the documentation you linked to? [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm). You tried only the first method of several methods described in it. Did you try the [UnicodeInput tool](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/index.htm) that the author linked to?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes

Answer (score 1):

http://granjow.net/unicode-input.html
This site gives you an AutoHotKey script for use with AHK, as well as a compiled exe version.

Here is the source code:

```
; (c) 2015 Simon A. Eugster <simon.eu@gmail.com> Public Domain
; This script listens for Shift+Ctrl+u and then shows a unicode input field.
; The unicode point (e.g. 2013 for an en dash) is then inserted in the active application.

; To run, download AutoHotkey from http://www.autohotkey.com/, save this script
; as e.g. UnicodeInput.ahk, and double-click it.

#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
;Menu, Tray, icon, unicode.ico
Menu, Tray, nostandard ; Put the following menu items on top (default: bottom)
Menu, Tray, add, Info, InfoHandler, -10
Menu, Tray, add
Menu, Tray, standard ; Add default menu items at the bottom
return

InfoHandler:
MsgBox Press Shift+Ctrl+U to get an entry field for unicode points (see decodeunicode.org for a list).`n`nAuthor: Simon A. Eugster <simon.eu@gmail.com> / granjow.net
return

+^u::
InputBox, codepoint, Unicode code point, U+
if not ErrorLevel
    Send {U+%codepoint%}
return
```